# Mapping node animation does not work in Blender Internal!

Tags: animation, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

In Blender Internal renderer mapping node keyframes do not produce inbetweens during animation. Other nodes do. In cycles they work. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround:

Instead of animating the mapping node I animate a blue value in a combine RGB node. It is possible because Blender converts RGB colors to XYZ coordinates automatically.

[image]